# Configure OpenSCEP to grant certificate requests automatically

Tags: linux, networking, ssl, ssl-certificate, linux-networking

I am trying to setup an OpenSCEP server that can grant certificates automatically instead of me running scepgrant command every time there is a new request? Can someone let me know how to proceed with the configuration?

From security point of view, I know this is not a good idea, what I am trying to do is automate some of the certificate enrollment tests. It would be great to have openscep grant certificate requests automatically.